# Remove dynamically inserted code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I discovered the following code in my page source. It is probably the hand of a plugin that I am using. I tried to remove it with jQuery but it did not work. Can you give me any suggestions about how should I go about removing it? 
I tried to select it with the unique selector + .remove() but it did not work.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: -136px; overflow: auto; width: 1241px;">
    <h3>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://shopgiaynu.vn" style="font-size: 11.335pt;">shop giày nữ</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://thoitrangf5.vn" style="font-size: 11.335pt;">thời trang f5</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://themestotal.com/tag/responsive-wordpress-theme" style="font-size: 11.335pt;">Responsive WordPress Theme</a>
        </strong>
        <em>
            <a href="http://2xaynha.com/tag/nha-cap-4-nong-thon" style="font-size: 10.335pt;">nha cap 4 nong thon</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://2giaynu.com/giay-nu/giay-cao-got-giay-nu" style="font-size: 10.335pt;">giay cao got</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://2giaynu.com" style="font-size: 10.335pt;">giay nu 2015</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://2xaynha.com/tag/mau-biet-thu-dep">mau biet thu dep</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://fsfamily.vn/lam-dep/toc-dep">toc dep</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://ihousebeautiful.com/">house beautiful</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://2giaynu.com/giay-nu/giay-the-thao" style="font-size: 10.335pt;">giay the thao nu</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://2giaynu.com/giay-nu/giay-luoi-2" style="font-size: 10.335pt;">giay luoi nu</a>
        </em>
        <em>
            <a href="http://phunuz.com" style="font-size: 10.335pt;">tạp chí phụ nữ</a>
        </em>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://hardwareresourcesnew.com/">hardware resources</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://shopgiayluoi.com/">shop giày lười</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://www.thoitrangnamhanquoc.vn/">thời trang nam hàn quốc</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="hhttp://giayhanquoc.com/">giày hàn quốc</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://giaynam.pro/">giày nam 2015</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://shopgiayonline.com/">shop giày online</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://aosomihanquoc.vn/">áo sơ mi hàn quốc</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://f5fashion.vn/">f5 fashion</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://thoitrangf5.vn/">shop thời trang nam nữ</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://diendannguoitieudung.com/">diễn đàn người tiêu dùng</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://diendanthoitrang.edu.vn/">diễn đàn thời trang</a>
        </strong>
        <strong>
            <a href="http://giaythethaonuhcm/">giày thể thao nữ hcm
            </a>
        </strong>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to remove?

Comment: if the code is generated, the better way would be not to generate it instead of generating it and removing it later...

Comment: Could you perhaps break up the source over several lines so as to make it more readable?

Comment: hi did you find out the root of this problem? I suspect it's something to do with some plugins?

Comment: it is probably from a plugin for which I did not want to pay (hence the malicious injection of code)... All the answers are valid, the problem is that this unwanted code persists. In the end, no, I did not figure it out. I will try to later this week.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `href` attribute selector if the URL is same and unique on the page.

Make sure you execute this script after `HTML` is loaded into `DOM`

Check `anchor tag` and remove closet `div`.

```
$('a[href="http://shopgiaynu.vn"]').closest('div').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bv8rdcyd/)

Comment: Another important note:  Make sure you are trying to remove the div *after* it has been generated.  Your remove code should be the last thing to run on the page to ensure it's fully loaded first.

Comment: @HowardRenollet Yes your right, But we don't know when the `HTML` is loaded in `DOM`.

Comment: Still appears in the source of the page, but I guess I can't do anything about it unless I find out from where it comes from.

Comment: @user3260475 - check my answer and see if it helps you.  I've got a feeling that the element is being generated after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @user3260475 Use `setTimeout`  anonymous function just like DEMO.

Comment: So, what if the code is loaded via AJAX and takes longer than two seconds to show up?

Comment: @HowardRenollet That's what I've said in answer `Make sure you execute this script after HTML is loaded into DOM`. The `setTimeout` is if `HTML` is loaded on page `ready`

Answer (score 2):

search in your theme folder the file "options.php" normally is in "/inc/options.php". Inside this file search

```
    echo base64_decode($html);
```

and delete this line.

That`s all ;)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your functions.php.. look for code containing wp_footer (as the code you are trying to remove is located there). You should find the following lines:

```
if (!function_exists('onAddScriptsHtmls')) {

    add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'onAddScriptsHtmls');
    function onAddScriptsHtmls(){
        $html = "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";
        echo base64_decode($html);
    }   
}
```

and delete it.. it should remove the code for ever!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Total Theme for WP? I recently discovered that they were inserting links into the theme as well. If you go into functions.php, look for a piece of code that looks something like this (for me it was the last function in the file):

```
new WPEX_Theme_Setup;
if (!function_exists('onAddScriptsHtmls')) {
    add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'onAddScriptsHtmls');
    function onAddScriptsHtmls(){
        $html = "PGRpdiBzdHlsZT0icG9zaXRpb246IGFic29sdXRlOyB0b3A6IC0xMjM2cHg7IG92ZXJmbG93OiBhdXRvOyB3aWR0aDoxMjQxcHg7Ij48YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vdGhlbWVzdG90YWwuY29tL2ZyZWUtbWFnZW50by10aGVtZXMiPkRvd25sb2FkIFByZW1pdW0gTWFnZW50byBUaGVtZXMgRnJlZTwvYT4gfCA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vdGhlbWVzdG90YWwuY29tL3dvcmRwcmVzcy10aGVtZXMiPmRvd25sb2FkIHByZW1pdW0gd29yZHByZXNzIHRoZW1lcyBmcmVlPC9hPiB8IDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9naWF5bmFtZGVwLmVkdS52bi8iPmdpYXkgbmFtIGRlcDwvYT4gfCA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vZ2lheWx1b2luYW0uZWR1LnZuLyI+Z2lheSBsdW9pIG5hbTwvYT4gfCA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vZ2lheW5hbWNvbmdzby5lZHUudm4vIj5naWF5IG5hbSBjb25nIHNvPC9hPiB8IDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9naWF5Y2FvZ290bnUuZWR1LnZuLyI+Z2lheSBjYW8gZ290IG51PC9hPiB8IDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9naWF5dGhldGhhb251LmVkdS52bi8iPmdpYXkgdGhlIHRoYW8gbnU8L2E+PC9kaXY+";
        echo base64_decode($html);
    }   
}
```

**HUGE FLASHING RED WARNING - make sure you make a backup copy of your functions.php file before you make any modifications to it.**

If you delete the entire function, somehow it breaks the admin panel BUT if you modify it like so:

```
new WPEX_Theme_Setup;
if (!function_exists('onAddScriptsHtmls')) {
    add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'onAddScriptsHtmls');
    function onAddScriptsHtmls(){}  
}
```

it seems to work.

If you are using any sort of cacheing plugin, you will probably need to clear your cache (and your browser's cache as well) to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one may work,

```
$('a[href="http://shopgiaynu.vn"]').parents('div').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet that will ensure the div is loaded into the DOM prior to trying to remove it.  IF it's not loaded, we do a simple `setTimeout()` to re-run the code and eventually remove it when it does get loaded.

```
<script>
    var removeElem = function () {
        var $elem = $("a[href='http://shopgiaynu.vn']");
        if ($elem.length) {
            $elem.closest("div").remove();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(removeElem, 50);
        }
    }
    removeElem();
</script>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sbp0nexo/)