# Top of wordpress site is displaying incorrectly, with spam text

Tags: css, wordpress

A website that I am working on has some text at the top reading ...Thông tin tiêu dùng - Tiêu dùng thông minh fashionshop

It leads to this website...

`http://diendannguoitieudung.com/`

I am making a wordpress website with rosa theme.

I can't seem to find anyway to remove the text at the top the page it?
Any help would be very appreciated?

Comment: This is malware site..read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072897/remove-dynamically-inserted-code you will get your answer

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Hi Leo
thanks for your fast reply.
I have had a read through the page however my theme doesn't have options.php to delete echo base64_decode($html);  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your site is hacked, checkout:
https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked